# Function as an argument to a method

Tags: c#, functional-programming

You can do anonymous functions in C# like you can in JavaScript:

JavaScript:

```
var s = (function ()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}());
```

C#:

```
var s = new Func<String>(() =>
{
    return "Hello World!";
})();
```

... In JavaScript you can pass functions to be executed by other functions. On top of that; you can pass parameters to the function which gets executed:

```
var f = function (message) // function to be executed
{
    alert(message);
};

function execute(f) // function executing another function
{
    f("Hello World!"); // executing f; passing parameter ("message")
}
```

Is the above example possible in C#?

**Update**

Use-case: I am iterating over a bunch of database, logging specific entities. Instead of calling my second function (`F()`) inside `Log()` of `Logger`, I'd like to call `F()` outside the class.

... Something along the lines of:

```
public void F(String databaseName)
{
}

public class Logger
{
    public void Log(Function f)
    {
        var databaseName = "";

        f(databaseName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely - you just need to give the method an appropriate signature:

```
public void Execute(Action<string> action)
{
    action("Hello world");
}
...
Execute(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Note that you do have to specify the particular delegate type in the parameter - you can't just declare it as `Delegate` for example.

EDIT: Your database example is exactly the same as this - you want to pass in a string and not get any output, which is exactly what `Action<string>` does. Except if you're trying to call an existing method (`F()` in your code) you don't even need a lambda expression - you can use method group conversions instead:

```
public void F(String databaseName)
{
}

public class Logger
{
    public void Log(Action<string> f)
    {
        var databaseName = "";

        f(databaseName);
    }
}

// Call it like this:
Logger logger = new Logger(...);
logger.Log(F);
```

Comment: Updated my question. Could you take another look. And perhaps be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: @roosteronacid: My example is exactly what you need: the `Action<string>` delegate is basically a delegate which takes a string and acts on it, and then doesn't return anything... just like `F(string)` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass delegate:

```
        var f = (Action<string>)
                (x =>
                     {
                         Console.WriteLine(x);
                     }
                );

        var execute = (Action<Action<string>>)
                      (cmd =>
                           {
                               cmd("Hello");
                           }
                      );
        execute(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

according your Update part:
 you need a container to keep your functions

```
 IList<Action<string>> actionList = new List<Action<Sstring>>();
```

in your Log() function you can add your F() to the container:

```
actionList.Add(F);
```

then invoke the function(s) somewhere outside:

```
 foreach (Action<string> func in actionList)
      {
           func("databasename");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
var s = new Func<String, string>((string name) =>
{
    return string.Format("Hello {0}!", name);
});
```

?